# How can I create a draft PayPal Invoice?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've been trying to mess around this for a while now, this is my create invoice function right now:

```py
async def create_invoice(client_email: str, item_name: str, item_price: int):

    payload = """{{
        "primary_recipients": [
            "billing_info": {{
                "name": {{
                    "given_name": "Test",
                    "surname": "Client"
                }},
                "business_name": "Test",
                "email_address": "{client_email}"
            }}
        ],
        "items": [
            "name": "{name}",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit_amount": [
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": {price}
            ]
        ],
        "detail": [
            "currency_code": "USD"
        ],
        "invoicer": [
            "business_name": "[REDACTED]",
            "email_address": "[REDACTED]"
        ],
        "configuration": [
            "template_id": "[REDACTED]"
        ],
        "amount": [
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "amount": {price}
        ]
    }}"""
    payload = payload.format(client_email=client_email, price=str(item_price), name=item_name)


    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer [REDACTED]',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Prefer': 'return=representation',
    }

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        resp = await session.post("https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices", data=payload, headers=headers)
        if resp.status != 200:
            print(resp.status)
        print(await resp.json())
```

I don't have access to Client's address, full name, so I'm trying to get around that because I believe it's possible unless I just provide dummy data? (Don't think I should do that)

The error I get is:

````
{'name': 'INVALID_REQUEST', 'message': 'Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.', 'debug_id': 'db080ca002d1d', 'details': [{'field': 'primary_recipients/0', 'location': 'body', 'description': "Cannot construct instance of `com.paypal.invoicing.v2.model.RecipientInfo` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('billing_info') at line:3, column:13"}], 'links': [{'href': 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors', 'method': 'GET'}]}```
````

Comment: I tried with the official PayPal example, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Why are there double brackets in billing_info? The error refers to it